# Get a tmux window index by name

Tags: tmux

Is there a way, being outside of tmux, in a specific session to get a window index by window name provided that there is
either 0 or 1 window with a given name?
I need this info to prevent creation of windows with the same name,
So I either get a window index to attach to or if there is no windows with the given name, create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this information with `tmux list-windows`. To list all windows in all sessions use the `-a` flag or specify a session id with `-t`.

If you want the window ID you would use something like:

```
tmux list-windows -F '#I "#W"' | awk '$2 ~ /"NAME"/ { print $1 }'
```

If you only want to know if it exists:

```
NAME=foo
if tmux list-windows -F '#W' | grep -q "^$NAME\$"; then
    echo $NAME exists
else
    # create new window ...
fi
```